# partition aspect of reduceByKey

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, reduce

Even though RDDs are legacy - and a bit of time on hand before next assignment - I am wondering:

- Why can `[reduceByKey][1]` can be called with `numPartitions`?
- Given that it works similar to `combineByKey` in Map Reduce, what is the point really?

Not so obvious to me. In real situations I suspect that it is not used often, one has already re-partitioned in general (based on my own observations).

Comment: *When called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs, returns a dataset of (K, V) pairs where the values for each key are aggregated using the given reduce function func, which must be of type (V,V) => V. Like in groupByKey, the number of reduce tasks is configurable through an optional second argument.* from [doc here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html)

Comment: @NikosM.  Whole point is I see no value in doing that. reduceByKey is already handy in that it does the combining. The only - in my eyes unlikely - situation is u may want to bump up number of partitions for a heavy aggr function. But at what cost? And unlikely - that's my point.

Comment: It adds fine control on the amount of paralellisdation, to the discretion of the programmer. I have no use case at this point handy but I can try to come up with sth

Comment: @NikosM.   I think this is a case of something that works but not really signiifcant in the overall scheme of things.

Comment: *In real life I suspect that it is not used often.* (like many fine-tuned optimsations, default settings constitute the majority of use cases for many different reasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RDD Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html)

> **reduceByKey(func, [numPartitions])**:   When called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs, returns a dataset of (K, V) pairs where the values for
>   each key are aggregated using the given reduce function func, which
>   must be of type (V,V) => V. Like in groupByKey, the number of reduce
>   tasks is configurable through an optional second argument.

So the second parameter controls the amount of parallelisation, similar to `groupByKey`:

> **groupByKey([numPartitions])**: When called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs, returns a dataset of (K, Iterable) pairs. Note: If you are
>   grouping in order to perform an aggregation (such as a sum or average)
>   over each key, using reduceByKey or aggregateByKey will yield much
>   better performance. Note: By default, the level of parallelism in the
>   output depends on the number of partitions of the parent RDD. You can
>   pass an optional numPartitions argument to set a different number of
>   tasks.

Quoting from [How is the number of RDD partitions decided in Apache Spark? | Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/805482/how-is-the-number-of-rdd-partitions-decided-in-apache-spark):

> How is this number determined? The way Spark groups RDDs into stages is described in the previous post. (As a quick reminder,
>   transformations like repartition and reduceByKey induce stage
>   boundaries.) The number of tasks in a stage is the same as the number
>   of partitions in the last RDD in the stage. The number of partitions
>   in an RDD is the same as the number of partitions in the RDD on which
>   it depends, with a couple exceptions: thecoalesce transformation
>   allows creating an RDD with fewer partitions than its parent RDD, the
>   union transformation creates an RDD with the sum of its parents’
>   number of partitions, and cartesian creates an RDD with their product.

**after question update**

from: [Optimizing Spark jobs for maximum performance](https://michalsenkyr.github.io/2018/01/spark-performance) (emphasis mine)

> [..]Partitioning characteristics frequently change on shuffle boundaries.
>   **Operations that imply a shuffle therefore provide a numPartitions
>   parameter that specify the new partition count** (by default the
>   partition count stays the same as in the original RDD).

Since Spark (RDD API) does no optimisation on its own (unlike SQL which many new programmers to Spark come from), it is imperative for the programmer to optimise the flow and parallelism of operations by herself (from same post).

> [..]This might possibly stem from many users’ familiarity with SQL
>   querying languages and their reliance on query optimizations. It is
>   important to realize that the RDD API doesn’t apply any such
>   optimizations.

Furthermore, `repartitioning` is usualy used but is typicaly costly and in various cases could be avoided or merged with other operations to improve overall performance (see linked post)

Comment: See comments in question, you are evading my question and I am familiar with the manual.

Comment: @thebluephantom I have no use case handy at this moment, but take a look at [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/805511/501848)

Comment: @thebluephantom, also take a look at [restricting num of partitions of certain operations](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-performance-tuning-groupBy-aggregation.html). I think this provides the intent behind the inclusion of the parameter in `reduceByKey`

Comment: I have a pretty good handle on all that, the question remains as is.

Comment: @thebluephantom, As I see it the intent is to provide user-refined optimisation for certain operations, and not relying on defaults as they may provide poor performance. I dont think there is anything more to that

Answer (score 2):

I think one major difference you can easily observe is that a `reduceByKey(func, numPartitions)` will be executed in single stage, while `repartition(numPartitions)` followed by `reduceByKey(func)` requires obviously two.

Lets check:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(("a", 1),("b", 1),("c",1),("a", 1),("b", 1),("c", 1),("a", 1),("b", 1),("c", 1)),3)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> def rbk(sumbykey:Int, i:Int) = sumbykey + i
rbk: (sumbykey: Int, i: Int)Int

scala> var res = rdd.reduceByKey(rbk(_,_),6)
res: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[8] at reduceByKey at <console>:27

scala> res.toDebugString
res8: String =
(6) ShuffledRDD[8] at reduceByKey at <console>:27 []
 +-(3) ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24 []

scala> res = rdd.repartition(6).reduceByKey(rbk)
res: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[13] at reduceByKey at <console>:29

scala> res.toDebugString
res9: String =
(6) ShuffledRDD[13] at reduceByKey at <console>:29 []
 +-(6) MapPartitionsRDD[12] at repartition at <console>:29 []
    |  CoalescedRDD[11] at repartition at <console>:29 []
    |  ShuffledRDD[10] at repartition at <console>:29 []
    +-(3) MapPartitionsRDD[9] at repartition at <console>:29 []
       |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24 []
```

So if you plan to increase parallelism of a reduce operation, the `reduceByKey(func, numPartitions)` version seems to have an advantage.

Comment: I read your post if I remember some time ago. But it still does not gel.

Comment: Not sure what "does not gel"?

Comment: read the question, i am not convinced the option is not that relevant in reality

Comment: Well, there are good and there are bad programming practices... I'm not ready to discuss which are prevalent **in reality** :)